# Seemingly basic C++ question

Tags: c++, email, visual-c++, enums, pop3

Alright, so this is annoying the hell out of me and I'm sure its a simple thing to do. Basically, I'm working with an open source C++ client called POCO to make a email client for a class...

Basically, I have a pop3 client object that retrieves emails from my email server, and then puts the emails in an object called MailMessage. Now, I want to be able to get my attachments, and the only functionality it seems that I have to do that is the following function:

```
static const std::string & contentTransferEncodingToString(
    ContentTransferEncoding encoding
);
```

Problem is, I had no idea what the following was:

> ContentTransferEncoding encoding

After digging into the source code, I found out it has something to do with "enums" (this is public by the way):

```
enum ContentTransferEncoding
    {
        ENCODING_7BIT,
        ENCODING_8BIT,
        ENCODING_QUOTED_PRINTABLE,
        ENCODING_BASE64
    };
```

Basically, the attachment I'm trying to open uses 7 bit encoding. Does ANYONE know how to deal with these enums, and how I can pass them into the contentTransferEncodingToString function?

Thank you so much for your efforts :)

> EDIT:
>
> So, unreal, but I didn't realize that
>   the function I was trying to access
>   was protected, it wasn't the enums, so
>   the way you all suggested to access
>   the enums was correct! And I guess the
>   way I was trying to access them was
>   also correct =P. Just a big stupid
>   mistake.
>
> But thanks for all your efforts!!!
>   Great community :)

Comment: Could you please post the actual error message and also post the actual code calling the contentTransferEncodingToString method.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either say

```
const std::string& s =  contentTransferEncodingToString(ENCODING_7BIT)
```

or

```
const std::string& s =  contentTransferEncodingToString(ContentTransferEncoding::ENCODING_7BIT)
```

Comment: I Ruben, it didn't seem to work... The first option had the following error:'ENCODING_8BIT' : undeclared identifier and the second option says that ContentTransferEncoding is a protected variable... Interesting since ContentTransferEncoding is public in the source code...

Comment: Assuming you're using VS, you could press F12 (go to declaration) to find out what ContentTransferEncoding is referring to (it might be e.g. a protected variable). If there are 2 and you're getting the wrong one, you'll need to disambiguate by putting the namespace prefixes in front of things

Comment: The other thing you could do is derive a class from MailMessage and add a method that uses ContentTransferEncoding in there [as one would be able to acccess protected enum values in that context]

Comment: The second example is not std C++.  Enumerations don't (yet) have a scope.  After a bit of searching, it seems that these enum's are declared in the class MailMessage inside namespace Net in namespace Poco.  So the correct qualification should be:  Poco::Net::MailMessage::ENCODING_7BIT.

Comment: @RC: For once, I had actually tested :P MSVC says: warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'A' used in qualified name (Looks like there are bigger problems here than this though :D)

Answer (score 3):

I googled about your problem and I found this :

http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html#16563

the complete namespace is Poco::Net::Message::ContentTransferEncoding so I would assume that you have to use either:

```
using namespace Poco::Net::Message;
```

or

```
string &s = contentTransferEncodingToString(Poco::Net::Message::ContentTransferEncoding::ENCODING_7BIT);
```

Comment: HI! I've actually tried that (the name is Poco:Net:MailMessage not Message), but it doesn't work, the problem is ContentTransferEncoding is protected...

Comment: my bad, Poco:Net:MailMessage. can you paste your entire code and error message ?

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the function you are calling is protected and static, which meant you have must have something like this :

```
class test : public Poco::Net::MailMessage{
  pubic:
    std::string myFunc(){
       // you can you the protected function here
       return ContentTransferEncoding(ENCODING_7BIT);
       // or 
       // because you have inherited all the class
       // return CTE_7BIT;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, just call your function with an element of the enum:

```
std::string str = contentTransferEncodingToString(ENCODING_8BIT);
```

Enums are a enumeration. You could get the same result by defining a bunch of

```
const int ENCODING_7BIT = 0;
const int ENCODING_8BIT = 1;
```

However, what would happen if you pass a 8 to your function? Defining an enum allows to

- Restrict the number of items you allow
- Don't have to worry about how it is represented (thus having some abstraction)

Comment: I have, but it definitely does not work. I get the following:

'ENCODING_8BIT' : undeclared identifier

Comment: I tried your modified version but to no avail... I got the following:

'Poco::Net::MailMessage::contentTransferEncodingToString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const int' to 'Poco::Net::MailMessage::ContentTransferEncoding'

Comment: Oh. Don't you have a namespace problem then ?

Comment: The modification was just to explain what enums where about (on the implementation side, not on the user side)

Comment: Ah, well I'm still quite confused :S. I dont understand what the compiler wants me to pass it...

Comment: That error message suggests that you could refer to the enum constant as `Poco::Net::MailMessage::ENCODING_7BIT`. Try passing that to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Is the class that tries to call contentTransferEncodingToString inheriting from Poco::NET::MailMessage?

The method [contentTransferEncodingToString](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html#16563) is protected not public and can thus only be called from a class that inherits MailMessage.

If this isn't the problem could you please post the error message exactly as printed by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> Does ANYONE know how to deal with these enums, and how I can pass them into the contentTransferEncodingToString function?

Several answers have shown the basic way to use `enum`s.  When trying them you're getting error messages that the syntax is correct, but that the methods that use those `enums` are not accessible from the scope you're in.

The answer, then, is to get into a scope where you can access what you want.

The methods in question are apparently `protected`, which means the way to access them is through a derived class.  I'm not saying this is good design, but it's clearly what POCO's designers expect you to use.

Comment: According to the docs the enum ContentTransferEncoding is not protected. (Protected members are defined by a blue icon with a P inside.) - http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html#16477

Comment: Edited, based on final answer by shawnjan

Answer (score 0):

So, unreal, but I didn't realize that the function I was trying to access was protected, it wasn't the enums, so the way you all suggested to access the enums was correct! And I guess the way I was trying to access them was also correct =P. Just a big stupid mistake.

But thanks for all your efforts!!! Great community :)